# Replace a url which is used in package with asset file in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm using Blockly (just for sample) package and it need  to call some API's to get some images like below :

```
https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/media/sprites.png 403
```

I want to change some config to avoid requesting to this URL (because client is offline), and change it with asset file.
the point is I don't want to change package config , I want to learn something like proxy and replace some URL's with  assets URL